# Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed in Moq Package in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, moq

I am Using Moq package for testing a Controller.
HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{  readonly IPermitRepository _repository;
    public HomeController(IPermitRepository rep)
    {            this._repository = rep;        }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello World";
        PermitModel model = _repository.GetPermitDetails();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

In HomeControllerTest.cs

```
 [TestClass]
 Public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {       
        var messagingService = new Mock<IPermitRepository>();
        var controller = new HomeController(messagingService.Object);

        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result.Model, typeof(PermitModel));
    }
}
```

But its giving error.
**Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected type:. Actual type:<(null)>.**

Can some one provide solution and also some inf about Moq package in MVC3. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moq returns `null` by default for each non void method call.

So when in your controller you call `_repository.GetPermitDetails();` it return `null` that's why  your test fails.

You need to call `Setup` on your method to return something:

```
var messagingService = new Mock<IPermitRepository>();
messagingService.Setup(m => m.GetPermitDetails()).Returns(new PermitModel());
var controller = new HomeController(messagingService.Object);
```

You can find more info in the [Moq quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) on how to customize the mock behaviour.